# Is there a compact way to find the indices of an occurrence of an element in a 2-D array?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

**Example:**

Say I have

```
var arr = new int[][] { 
   { 1, 9, 4 }, 
   { 2, 4, 4 },
   { 3, 0, 5 }
};
```

and say I want the indices of `3`. So I want a method that does the equivalent of

```
Tuple<int,int> indices; 
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
   for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; ++j)
      if(arr[i][j] == 3)
         return new Tuple<int,int>() { i, j }
```

ideally without having to write any extension methods and ideally in a way that is compact and efficient.

Comment: Are you sure `var arr = new int[][]` and not `new int[,]` because the way defined, the example does not compile. In other words, are you asking for *jagged* or *2d* array.

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't want `[,]` because then I can't use LINQ on it

Comment: Then call it correctly and use example that compiles.

Comment: Your `for loop` is best efficiency you can get in your example and your specifications.

Comment: Calling things incorrectly without providing an [mcve] is a major, super classy way of doing it for everyone who is not a loser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in LINQ in a "compact" manner - but as the comments suggest, a regular loop will trounce this for efficiency:

```
var indexes = arr.Select((a, x) => a.Select((v, y) => new { X = x, Y = y })
    .Where(z => arr[z.X][z.Y] == 3)).SelectMany(x => x);
```

Even using LINQ, you still have to traverse the entire collection and build up the indexes (into an anonymous type here) and determine if they meet your criteria (and then flatten the result using `SelectMany`).

Also note this will return all instances, to get the first occurance simply throw a `.First()` on the end.

I'd strongly recommend a static helper or extension method in this case: